# Google-Bigquery: Query scans whole table instead of given range in partition table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a fact table containing 50 million records named AccountLines partitioned by Posting_Date_New. When I'm filtering records on particular partitioned column then my query works fine and scan only limited data between given range. But when I made join with Dimension table on the basis of Posting_Date_New column and filter on Financial Year then it scans whole table. How can I solve this problem? I need to join my Fact Table with Dimension table and filter on Dimension table's columns without scanning whole table. Please help.

My queries are as follows.

--Query complete (5.542 sec elapsed, 244.37 MB processed)

```
select ah.ChargeGroup, sum(Amount) Amount from SSIS_STAGING.AccountLine acc
inner join SSIS_STAGING.Dim_Times_BI_Clustering dd on dd.Posting_Date_New = acc.Posting_Date_New
inner join SSIS_STAGING.BranchHierarchy br on br.CostCenterId = acc.BookingBranchID
inner join SSIS_STAGING.Accounts_Hierarchy ah on ah.Account = acc.G_L
where acc.Posting_Date_New between '2018-04-01' and '2019-03-31' and ZoneName = 'BU-North'
group by ah.ChargeGroup
```

--Query complete (16.530 sec elapsed, 5.51 GB processed)

```
select ah.ChargeGroup, sum(Amount) Amount from SSIS_STAGING.AccountLine acc
inner join SSIS_STAGING.Dim_Times_BI_Clustering dd on dd.Posting_Date_New = acc.Posting_Date_New
inner join SSIS_STAGING.BranchHierarchy br on br.CostCenterId = acc.BookingBranchID
inner join SSIS_STAGING.Accounts_Hierarchy ah on ah.Account = acc.G_L
where dd.FinancialYear = '2018-19' and ZoneName = 'BU-North'
group by ah.ChargeGroup
```

Comment: have you tried adding `AND acc.Posting_Date_New between '2018-04-01' and '2019-03-31'` into the WHERE clause - so you actually explicitly state which partitions to only scan? because now - your quesry has no idea that you need specific partitions!

Answer (score 0):

To [prune partitioned table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#querying_partitioned_tables_1) you need to use the timestamp in a where clause:

## standardSQL

SELECT
t1.name,
t2.category
FROM
table1 t1
INNER JOIN
table2 t2
ON t1.id_field = t2 field2
WHERE
t1.ts = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()

This being said as [BigQuery is performs better with denormalize](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-input#denormalize_data_whenever_possible) data.